# Show current category in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

In layered navigation view, my themes show which filters are currently applied to the view. However, it doesn't show which category you are currently in.

I guess I have to edit the state.phtml, but what would I add in order to get current category?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `magento registry variable`

***Mage::registry('current_category')***

or use

`Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()` for getting current category object

Second option is best

Comment: Thanks! Isn't there any stock functionality to show the current category in state.phtml? I see it in lot of other themes, but it's not present in my theme.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the current category like that

`Mage::registry('current_category')`

Comment: Thanks! Isn't there any stock functionality to show the current category in state.phtml? I see it in lot of other themes, but it's not present in my theme.

Comment: can you show me example of that?

Comment: http://www.manadev.com/demo/mod-filters/index.php/apparel/shoes.html?cat=16

Comment: https://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/free-ajax-layered-navigation-extension.html try this extension it is free

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. However, it doesn't work on my page. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: what to you want kindly tell me briefly so i can help you